# How to assess sentence complexity

Tags: terminology, computational-linguistics

I'm not really a linguist but I am analysing some medical free text so that I'll be able to extract various phrases using regular expressions.

I have noticed that the sentences are usually very short, do not contain subclauses and are very factual in their content. I want to be able to quantify the complexity of the terms used so that I can demonstrate that the free text is a simple substrate for my regular expression extraction to work on.

How do I demonstrate sentence complexity? Is there some linguistic terminology I can look up that analyses sentence complexity

Comment: The traditional way is to define them as simple, compound. complex or compound-complex, depending on the occurrence of sub clauses and coordinated main clauses. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @BillJ.  Yes. Do you know of a package in R or ntlk that can help me do this as I have 1500 reports to go through.

Comment: That would be beyond my knowledge, I'm afraid. The terms I used are just broad grammatical ones to describe the four basic clause structures.

Comment: Why do you care about having a metric for complexity? Just parse out the fact however complex.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology used is either *syntactic complexity* (see also this question on [languagelearning.se]: [Measuring syntactic complexity](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/measuring-syntactic-complexity)) or [*Readability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability). Specifically for the English language there are several formulæ available (e.g., the [Dale–Chall formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale%E2%80%93Chall_readability_formula)) to determine the readability of a sentence from easy-to-count features. Those formulæ are fitted to empirical judgements of the readbility.